# fetching records for previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
item    loc     year    month   quantity        startdate
XYZ     A       2020    1       3               23-06-2020
ABC     B       2020    2       218             24-06-2020
SDC     C       2020    6       107             25-06-2020
QWE     D       2020    7       144             25-06-2020
XYZ     A       2019    12      89              23-06-2020
ABC     B       2019    11      218             24-06-2020
SDC     C       2020    5       117             25-06-2020
QWE     D       2020    6       144             25-06-2020
```

if i consider the above table then my output should look like this:

```
item    loc     year    month   quantity        startdate
XYZ     A       2020    1       89              23-06-2020
ABC     B       2020    2       3               24-06-2020
SDC     C       2020    6       117             25-06-2020
QWE     D      2020    7        144             25-06-2020
```

so u can see that only quantities values changed and that we are taking from previos months and rest columns values are as it is.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and date/time functions are very different in the various products). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect.

Comment: @GMB suppose if i have data for january month 2020......then i need to take the quantity for december month.................and my output should have the dates from january itself except quantity should be from previous month

Comment: @MradulGupta: please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62488417/edit) to show us the resultset that would correspond to your sample data, as tabular text. You might also want to add data that belongs to another month, so it is more representative of your actual use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want window function `lag()`. For your sample data, this would produce the desired results:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        item, 
        loc,
        year,
        month,
        lag(quantity) over(partition by item, loc order by year, month) quantity,
        startdate
    from mytable
) t
where quantity is not null
```

Comment: urs answer is right...but there is one more scenario.....suppose for an item,loc if there is data for january,february and april............since there is no data for march so for april prev quantity should be zero

Answer (score 0):

Consider query which works in Access database:

```
SELECT Table1.*, (SELECT TOP 1 quantity FROM Table1 AS Dupe 
                 WHERE Dupe.item = Table1.item AND Dupe.loc = Table1.loc 
                 AND DateSerial(Dupe.[Year],Dupe.[Month],1)<DateSerial(Table1.[Year],Table1.[Month],1) 
                 ORDER BY DateSerial(Dupe.[Year],Dupe.[Month],1)) AS PrevQty
FROM Table1;
```

If you want to return 0 when there is a gap in month sequence, consider:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Nz((SELECT quantity FROM Table1 AS Dupe
                 WHERE Dupe.item = Table1.item AND Dupe.loc = Table1.loc 
                 AND DateSerial(Dupe.[Year],Dupe.[Month],1)=DateAdd("m",-1,DateSerial(Table1.[Year],Table1.[Month],1)) 
                 ORDER BY DateSerial(Dupe.[Year],Dupe.[Month],1)),0) AS PrevQty
FROM Table1;
```

Or

```
SELECT Q1.*, Nz(Q2.quantity,0) AS PrevQty FROM (
    SELECT Table1.*, DateSerial([Year],[Month],1) AS FD FROM Table1) AS Q1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Table1.*, DateAdd("m",+1,DateSerial([Year],[Month],1)) AS PD FROM Table1) AS Q2 
ON Q1.FD=Q2.PD AND Q1.item=Q2.item and Q1.loc=Q2.loc;
```

Comment: suppose if i have data for january month 2020......then i need to take the quantity for december month.2019................and my output should have the dates from january itself except quantity should be from previous month data

Comment: Try it and let us know what happens.

Comment: i have edited the qn ...................it will be more clear to u

Comment: You should still try my suggestion. Certainly can't hurt to.

Comment: urs answer is right...but there is one more scenario.....suppose for an item,loc if there is data for january,february and april............since there is no data for march so for april prev quantity should be zero –

Comment: See revised answer.